# Any idea why my mesh is doing this when I shade smooth?

Tags: mesh, shaders, transparency

I've been trying to fix this for hours from remaking the inside of the mouth and deleting any accidental extra vertices but it still has this problem and appears transparent when I export it to Mixamo

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, have you checked the normals? the inner faces? could you please share the part with the problem? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to recalculate faces normals ?

This can be found in *Edit Mode* (while wrong faces are selected) under *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*.